# Need assistance regarding few concepts of objective-c protocols

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

1> Is there any other way to use/avail/consume protocol without doing this `@interface MyClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol>`.

2> Can a class become a delegate of delegating class without doing this `@interface MyClass : NSObject <SomeProtocol>`.

3> Am I correct regarding these

`id<aProtocol> *myVar1;` this means that `myVar1` will hold an object of any class but that   class must implement `<aProtocol>`?

`AClass<bProtocol> *myVar2;` this means that `myVar2` will hold an object of `AClass` and it must also implement `<bProtocol>`?

4> What this is doing `(MyClass <someProtocol> *)[[MyClass alloc] init];` and `MyClass` in its interface **not** inheriting `<someProtocol>`.

Comment: What's with the close votes? The OP has asked direct questions which is better than the usual `I wrote some code... it doesn't work - help`  style questions that get asked all the time.

Comment: It's also probably worth noting that you don't "inherit" a protocol, you "conform" to it. In Paul's answer below, class `myClass` conforms to protocol `someProtocol` (you should capitalise class, protocol and category names).

Comment: @wmorrison365 thanks for pointing out class naming convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, as long as an object implements the required interface of the protocol then that object can essentially stand in for an object that explicitly conforms to a protocol. If you do this then you loose the compiler helping you out confirming that you implement the required methods. So it's normally best to just be explicit and declare that your class conforms to a protocol.

   When I say `as long as an object implements the required interface of the protocol` I mean that the object informally conforms in that sense that it implements the methods required but simply does not make it explicit that it is trying to conform. e.g. this object would be a valid `UITableViewDataSource` as it implements the `@required` methods, however it just does not declare such.

   ```
   @interface MyObject : NSObject
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
   @end
   ```

   Again you should just make these relationships clear and actually say that you conform with `@interface MyObject : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource>`
2. **a)**`id<aProtocol> *myVar1;` should be written without the asterisk `id<aProtocol> myVar1;` and this is saying that you have a variable called `myVar1` that should conform to `aProtocol` - this could be a lie (see answer to 3)
   **b)** This is correct except `it must also implement <bProtocol>` is too strong, what this is saying is that you have a variable called `myVar2` and that it should conforms to `bProtocol` - again this could be a lie (see answer to 3)
3. Here you are performing a cast from the return type of the method which will be `myClass` to `myClass<someProtocol>`. This is essentially you saying to the compiler "I know the object returns an object of type `myClass` but really I am telling you it will be `myClass<someProtocol>`". Essentially if `myClass` is not defined as `@interface myClass : NSObject <someProtocol>` then you are lying to the compiler and there is a chance that you will introduce bugs that the compiler cannot tell you about.

You should be careful about casting things to silence the compiler (the compiler is very clever) for example I could compile this code without any issues but it will crash at runtime

```
UIView *view = (id)@"Hey I'm not a view";
view.frame = CGRectZero;
```

Comment: For (2b) I think you mean `<bProtocol>`.

Comment: @Paul.s Thanks a lot for replying. I didn't get this point "object implements the required interface of the protocol", do you mean like this MyClass<someProtocol>?

Comment: @Paul.s Please tell variable is just to hold something, how it can confirm to protocol, the object that is going to be store in that variable should confirm to protocol? I am bit confused...

Comment: 1. It's not exactly the same. If you check whether it conforms to the protocol at runtime using `conformsToProtocol:` it will say no. To make it the same you would need to add the protocol to the class at runtime, with the `class_addProtocol()` runtime function.

Comment: @newacct good catch - are there any cases where this rigidity is enforced? For example my tableView doesn't care to ask if the object I assign as the `dataSource` conforms to `UITableViewDataSource` it just works

Comment: @Paul.s: I don't know of any cases in Cocoa. But if someone is writing their own library, and they are tempted to use `conformstoProtocol:`, they should know this.

Answer (score 0):

To supplement Paul.s's answer, there is also the concept of an "informal protocol" which does not have to be adopted byt client code (because an informal protocol is really a Category on NSObject, and not a Protocol at all). This concept has now been largely superceded with the notion of "optional" methods in a protocol (the protocol can declare methods that can optionally be implemented in your `myClass`).

See [ios protocol docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html) for more info.